# Azure Data Factory - Copy Activity - rest api collection reference

Tags: rest, azure-data-factory

Helo eveyone,

I am fairly new to Data Factory and I need to copy information from Dynamics Business Central's Rest API. I am struggling with the "Details" type entities such as "invoiceSalesHeader".

The api for that entity forces me to provide a header ID as a filter. In that sense, I would have to loop x times (a few thousand) and call the Rest API to retreive the lines of each sales invoice. I find that completely ridiculous and am trying to find other ways to get the information.

To avoid doing that, I am trying to get the information by calling the "salesInvoice" entity and use "$expand=salesInvoiceLines".

That gets me the information I need but inside data factory's Copy Activity, I am struggling with what I should put as a "collection reference" so that I end up with one row per salesInvoiceLine.

The data returned is an array of sales invoices with a sub array of invoice lines.

If I select "salesInvoiceLines" as the collection reference, I end up with "$['value'][0]['salesInvoiceLines']" and that only gives me the lines for the first invoice (since there is an index of zero).

What should I put in Collection Reference so that I get one row per salesInvoiceLine

[image]

Comment: It is not support to foreach nested array in ADF.

Comment: You can save the json file to Azure Cloud and then use Azure data flow to flatten it.

Comment: Hi @David Laplante, please correct me if I understand you wrong in the answer.

Comment: @David Laplante how did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It is not support to foreach nested json array in ADF.
Alternatively, we can use a Flattern activity in data flow to flatten the nested json array.

Here is my example:
This is my example json data, the structure is like yours:

```json
[
 {
 "id": 1,
 "Value": "January",
 "orders":[{"orderid":1,"orderno":"qaz"},{"orderid":2,"orderno":"edc"}]
 },
 {
 "id": 2,
 "Value": "February",
 "orders":[{"orderid":3,"orderno":"wsx"},{"orderid":4,"orderno":"rfv"}]
 },
 {
 "id": 3,
 "Value": "March",
 "orders":[{"orderid":5,"orderno":"rfv"},{"orderid":6,"orderno":"tgb"}]
 },
 {
 "id": 11,
 "Value": "November",
 "orders":[{"orderid":7,"orderno":"yhn"},{"orderid":8,"orderno":"ujm"}]
 }
]
```

In the dataflow, we can select the header of the nested json array, here is `orders`:
[image]

Then we can see the result, we have transposed  the JSON `orders` array with 2 objects (orderid, orderno) into 8 flatten rows:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Another way if you are saving data to SQL database is to dump it as JSON to some table and then process in SQL.

For example based on the JSON provided above:

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(MAX) = '[{"id": 1, "Value": "January","orders":[{"orderid":1,"orderno":"qaz"},{"orderid":2,"orderno":"edc"}]},{"id": 2,"Value": "February","orders":[{"orderid":3,"orderno":"wsx"},{"orderid":4,"orderno":"rfv"}]}]'

SELECT id, [Value], orderid, orderno
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH ([id] INT,
      [Value] nvarchar(4000),
      [orders] nvarchar(MAX) AS JSON )
OUTER APPLY OPENJSON([orders]) WITH (orderid INT, [orderno] [nvarchar](512))
```

And then you can run a stored procedure to insert it to the desired place.